# Finding all ordered pairs $(x,y)$ for $\frac{3x-4y}{xy}=-8$ and $\frac{2x+7y}{xy}=43$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have to find all $x,y$ pairs for the following:

$\frac{3x-4y}{xy}=-8$,

$\frac{2x+7y}{xy}=43$

The hint states that I should rewrite the left-sides of the equations. There are two routes I can see being taken here. First one would involve removing the denominators, the second one would be writing these fractions in their reciprocal form like  $\frac{3}{y}+\frac{4}{x}$. For the sake of simplicity, I'll just remove the denominator by multiplying both sides.

This gives me the following:

$3x-4y = -8xy$,

$2x+7y = 43xy$

At this point it seems that I can't substitute any variable nicely without fractions. That means that I should go for the elimination of $x$.

$6x + 21y = 138xy$

$-$

$6x - 8y = -16xy$

---

$29y = 154xy \therefore 29 = 154x \therefore \frac{29}{154}=x$ Now that does not look right. I get the same result by just splitting up the fractions...

Comment: The hint that they gave you is good. Work with it.

Comment: But I arrive at the same conclusion. I will edit the post.

Comment: @Vocaloidas $$\,$$ The method of assigning two new variables to $1/x$ and $1/y$, as suggested in others' answers, will work. It reduces the problem to a system of two linear equations in two variables. $$\,$$ However, it requires the cleverness to decide to choose those particular variable assignments, which may seem like some kind of magic trick if seeing it for the first time. $$\,$$ Another method, one that doesn't involve such trickery, is to eliminate the annoying $xy$ terms. Simply multiply the top equation by $43$, multiply the bottom equation by $8$, then add them together. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint means that for $x,y\neq 0$

$$\frac{3x-4y}{xy}=-8 \iff \frac 3 y-\frac 4 x=-8$$

$$\frac{2x+7y}{xy}=43 \iff \frac 2 y+\frac 7 x=43$$

and then set $u=\frac1x$, $v=\frac1y$.

Comment: I don't understand the idea behind setting $u = \frac1x, v = \frac1y$, sure it makes the equation look better, but it's not a standard way of solving this in my book.

Comment: The idea is to obtain a linear system of equations once we have $u$ and $v$ we can find $x$ and$ y$.

Comment: You don't have to stick to the "standard way" to solve something

Comment: @helpme Yes of course we can also solve in other ways. The idea here was to give an advice on the effectiveness of the hint.

Comment: Oh I was addressing the OP, but I see what you mean

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there, based on what you did at the very start! (The rest is a distraction.)

Set 1/x =a, 1/y=b. What do the equations become?

Comment: Why am I just randomly assigning variables?

Comment: You are doing a change of variables to simplify the problem to something that you already know (i.e. System of linear equations).

Answer (score 0):

Your method looks correct, but you've made a careless mistake somewhere after "This gives me the following". If you find it, you should get the correct answer.